# Why does Fragment recreate itself when Adapter no longer exist?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have an `Activity` that creates `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I then create `Fragment` inside of `getItem()`. `Fragment` needs to grab some data from `Activity` which will need to sync data on cloud.

This works perfectly for the first load. `Adapter` is initiated **after** response come back from server. Thus `Fragment` will always have data handy since it is created within `Adapter` which is created **after** I have data. This however breaks when OS recreate the `Activity`. While `Activity` is still running and getting data from server, `Fragment` started its recreation. Even though `Adapter` is not yet created in the new `Activity`. Most weird thing is even after I create a new `Adapter`, I don't see any calls happening in the new `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the documentation of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

> Implementation of {@link PagerAdapter} that uses a {@link Fragment} to manage each page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's state.

That means that the `ViewPager` you initialized your adapter with will try to restore the state of initiated fragments by using a fragment manager it was initialized with.